# Pegar 6 numeros de um string dentro de uma array

Tags: php

Tenho um resultado de uma consulta DOM em uma array, conforme abaixo:

```
array(10) {
[0]=>  string(19) "6920709201700750550"
[1]=>  string(16) "6920702500550400"
[2]=>  string(14) "69207000550400"
[3]=>  string(19) "7740641201800750550"
[4]=>  string(16) "7740642500550400"
[5]=>  string(20) "79378270201900750550"
[6]=>  string(16) "7937822500550400"
[7]=>  string(20) "79575693201900750550"
[8]=>  string(16) "7957562500550400"
[9]=>  string(14) "79575600550400"
}
```

Preciso pegar os 6 primeiros números iniciando da array[0] sem repetir em um numero indefinido. Ou seja, no exemplo acima, preciso dos números 692070, 774064, 793782 e 795756.
Ja tentei varias respostas aqui do Stackoverflow, mas nenhum funcionou. Como não sou programador, fica um pouco mais difícil. Se puderem ajudar fico agradecido.

Comment: "6 primeiros números iniciando da array[0] sem repetir em um numero indefinido", poderia explicar melhor isso?

Comment: Você quer fazer algo como o SQL `GROUP BY`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode pegar os seis primeiros dígitos dessa string com uma expressão regular, `^\d{6}`, o resultado da captura é armazenado em `$m`.

O if faz duas verificações, a primeira é se a captura de `preg_match()` retornou algum valor e a segunda é se esse valor `$m[0]` existe no array `$novo` se não existir ele é adicionado.

```
$arr = ['6920709201700750550', '6920702500550400', '69207000550400', '7740641201800750550', '7740642500550400',
'79378270201900750550', '7937822500550400', '79575693201900750550', '7957562500550400', '79575600550400', '123', '123abc'];

$novo = [];

foreach($arr as $item){
    preg_match('/^\d{6}/', $item, $m);
    if(isset($m[0]) && !in_array($m[0], $novo)){
        $novo[] = $m[0];
    }
}

print_r($novo);
```

[Exemplo - ideone](https://ideone.com/MkcKiZ)

Comment: Perfeito. Só uma dúvida: caso eu tenha 50 strings, esse código funcionara da mesma forma?

Comment: @JohnPabloMartins ele não vai adicionar itens repetidos idependente da quantidade.

Comment: Ok. justamente o que precisava. Funcionou perfeitamente.